# Magento 2 : Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails while saving a duplicate category

Tags: magento2, database, category, url-rewrite, data-migration

**I have installed Duplicate categories Extension in the client site(Magento 2.3.2), while duplicating categories I'm facing this error,**

> {"0":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add
> or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`my_db`.`catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`, CONSTRAINT
> `CAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
> (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_), query was: INSERT  INTO` catalog_url_rewrite_product_category `(`url_rewrite_id`,`category_id`,`product_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?),

```
{"0":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`, CONSTRAINT `CAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_), query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` (`url_rewrite_id`,`category_id`,`product_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Statement\\Pdo\\Mysql->_execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Statement.php:303]\n#2 Zend_Db_Statement->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Abstract.php:480]\n#3 Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query() called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Abstract.php:238]\n#4 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:542]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->_query() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:617]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->query() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:2067]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->insertArray() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/DB\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Mysql.php:2024]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->insertMultiple() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-url-rewrite\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Category\/Product.php:58]\n#9 Magento\\CatalogUrlRewrite\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Product->saveMultiple() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-url-rewrite\/Model\/Category\/Plugin\/Storage.php:57]\n#10 Magento\\CatalogUrlRewrite\\Model\\Category\\Plugin\\Storage->afterReplace() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n#11 Scriptlodge\\UrlRewrite\\Model\\Storage\\DbStorage\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#12 Scriptlodge\\UrlRewrite\\Model\\Storage\\DbStorage\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Scriptlodge\/UrlRewrite\/Model\/Storage\/DbStorage\/Interceptor.php:39]\n#13 Scriptlodge\\UrlRewrite\\Model\\Storage\\DbStorage\\Interceptor->replace() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-url-rewrite\/Model\/UrlRewriteBunchReplacer.php:35]\n#14 Magento\\CatalogUrlRewrite\\Model\\UrlRewriteBunchReplacer->doBunchReplace() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-url-rewrite\/Observer\/CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver.php:114]\n#15 Magento\\CatalogUrlRewrite\\Observer\\CategoryProcessUrlRewriteSavingObserver->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php:66]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Model\/AbstractModel.php:829]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->afterSave() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/Category.php:1171]\n#21 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category->afterSave() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/EntityManager\/Observer\/AfterEntitySave.php:34]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\EntityManager\\Observer\\AfterEntitySave->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php:66]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]\n#26 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/EntityManager\/EventManager.php:52]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\EntityManager\\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/EntityManager\/Operation\/Create.php:123]\n#28 Magento\\Framework\\EntityManager\\Operation\\Create->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/EntityManager\/EntityManager.php:96]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\EntityManager\\EntityManager->save() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Category.php:1106]\n#30 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category->save() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#31 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#32 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/Indexer\/Fulltext\/Plugin\/Category.php:44]\n#33 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\Indexer\\Fulltext\\Plugin\\Category->addCommitCallback() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog-search\/Model\/Indexer\/Fulltext\/Plugin\/Category.php:28]\n#34 Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\Indexer\\Fulltext\\Plugin\\Category->aroundSave() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#35 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Cache\/FlushCacheByTags.php:68]\n#36 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Cache\\FlushCacheByTags->aroundSave() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#37 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#38 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Category\/Interceptor.php:52]\n#39 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Interceptor->save() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Model\/AbstractModel.php:655]\n#40 Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->save() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#41 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#42 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#43 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Model\/Category\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#44 Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Interceptor->save() called at [app\/code\/MyVendor\/DuplicateCategories\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Category\/Save.php:141]\n#45 MyVendor\\DuplicateCategories\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Category\\Save->duplicate() called at [app\/code\/MyVendor\/DuplicateCategories\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Category\/Save.php:63]\n#46 MyVendor\\DuplicateCategories\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Category\\Save->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:108]\n#47 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#48 MyVendor\\DuplicateCategories\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Category\\Save\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#49 MyVendor\\DuplicateCategories\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Category\\Save\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#50 MyVendor\\DuplicateCategories\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Category\\Save\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/MyVendor\/DuplicateCategories\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Category\/Save\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#51 MyVendor\\DuplicateCategories\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Category\\Save\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:159]\n#52 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:99]\n#53 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#54 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#55 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#56 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#57 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:137]\n#58 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#59 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#60 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/trsadmin\/duplicatecategories\/category\/save\/key\/e136aa1e297bb63596d0a11d8a079ef27c663ca61e6b959948bfe185175a0bd6\/","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

### EDIT

> Error is showing at this line in `$copy->save()`

```
$copy = $this->categoryFactory->create();

$copy->setIsActive(true);
$copy->setName($category->getName());
$copy->setParentId($parentCategory->getId());   
$copy->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$copy->setData('description',$sub_description);
$copy->setData('meta_description',$sub_meta_description);
$copy->setData('meta_keywords',$sub_meta_keywords);    

$newUrl = $this->getNewUrl($category, $parentCategory,$count);
$copy->setUrlKey($newUrl);

if($copy_products == 1){   

    $copy->setPostedProducts($category->getProductsPosition());
}
$copy->save();
```

> I have also tried saving with `store id` and `repository` it doesn't
> work for the category that I want to duplicate, code is working for other categories. I think there is a non-existential `category id` or `product id` i don't understand how do I find that in the database.

**Client has done Migration on the site before installing the module.**

**Does anyone has any idea? why this error is showing and how do I resolve it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I resolved this issue with the help of this [Reference link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298)**

Ran below query to find and delete duplicates,

> Delete from url_rewrite where entity_type='product' and entity_id NOT
> IN (Select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);

**After deleting I ran upgrade-deploy and indexer commands and it's
working for me.**

**Hope it Helps.**